# Como passar uma parâmetro/variável na inicialização de uma class PHP?

Tags: php

Como faço para inicializar uma class PHP passando ao mesmo tempo um parâmetro. Igual ao PDO que é inicializado passando parâmetros como dados para a conexão com o banco de dados.

No meu caso eu quero simplesmente passar uma ID na inicialização. Ex:

```
$user = new User($id);
```

E depois de passado o parâmetro usando a função construct para carregar todas as informações desse usuário, sem a necessidade de de chamar alguma função manualmente para tal ação.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usa um [construtor](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.decon.php):

```
class User {

   protected $id;
   public $dados;
   public function __construct($id) {
      $this->id = $id; // aqui já tens o teu id
      // echo $this->id; // vai imprimir 4 e podes fazer o que quiseres com ele ao longo dos metodos/atributos desta instância
      // aceder à base de dados, SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = $id, 4 neste caso

      // depois já terás os dados que queres acerca do utilizador
      $this->dados = array('id' => 4, 'nome' => 'Miguel', 'email' => 'hdj@jdj.di');
   }
}

$u = new User(4);
echo $u->dados['email']; // hdj@jdj.di
```

Neste caso `$dados` é só um exemplo de um retorno da informação da base de dados

[DEMONSTRAÇÃO](http://ideone.com/L32vVw)

Comment: O que faz o "protected" ?

Comment: @ThomsonTorvalds protected é para dizer que apenas esta e as classes que extendem esta têm acesso a esta propriedade, podes pôr private para que seja só esta se preferires

Comment: @ThomsonTorvalds, completei um pouco mais para veres ao certo o que podes fazer